# How can I import Excel data into an Combo box in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, combobox

I have one combo box, in that I want to fill the combo items from a separate ms excel file I have.After select one item from the combo box if I press save button  the entire data should be saved in the database.

eg: In combo I am selecting the product name and click save means the product name, purchase rate and sales rate etc should be to save in db.)....

Thanks in advance and sorry 4 my bad english.

Comment: still yet i didnt start..... i have no idea  to do diz

Answer (score 0):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
          try
            {

                con.Open();

                str = "select * from [sheet1$]";

                com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);

                oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);

                ds = new DataSet();

                oledbda.Fill(ds, "[sheet1$]");

                con.Close();

                dt = ds.Tables["[sheet1$]"];

                int i = 0;

                for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count -1; i++)

                {

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
                {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }


        }
```

**Link for further details :**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/7482/

Also refer [This](http://forumarray.com/c-export-import-to-excel-with-combo-box-487357) link for combo box details.